# Today I touched her hand (after / in / since / for) 3837 days

Tags: prepositions

Today I met a girl after a long time. So I want to say the following:

> Today I touched her hand {**after**|**in**|**since**|**for**} 3837 days.

What is the more appropriate option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct answer is obviously "after". There is no difference between after a long time and after 3837 days.

let me provide examples for the other prepositions:

**in**: I'll be able to touch her hand in two weeks (before or at the end of a particular period)

**since**:I haven't touched her hand since 2010. (from a particular time in the past until now)

**for**: I haven't touched her hand for years. (shows the duration of time)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are planning to not let go of her for more than 10 years, the correct word is 'after'.